# Can you assign a char a default name without scanf in c?

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I'm trying to make my game more interactive, where the players enter their names and play.
Is there a way to make it so if there isn't a player 2, the char player2 can get a default name?

```
#define DEF "CPU"

printf(" Enter name for Player 1:\n");
scanf(" %s", &player1 );

printf("Is there a Player 2? [y/n]");
scanf(" %c", &mult);

if( mult == y){
    printf("Enter name for Player 2:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &player2);
}else{
    printf(" The CPU will be your opponent!\n");
    &player2 = DEF ;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem now? you already asking if a player 2 is ther?!

Comment: Read the compiler error/warning message first. Then fix them.

Comment: @Rizier123, I want to make it so that if there is a player 2, their name will be entered with a scanf prompt. If there isn't a player 2, then player2 will be assigned the name CPU by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEF "CPU"

void clean_stdin(void) {
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main() {

    char player1[20], player2[20];
    char mult;


    printf("Enter name for Player 1:\n>");
    fgets (player1, 20, stdin);
    clean_stdin();

    printf("Is there a Player 2? [y/n]:");
    scanf(" %c", &mult);
    clean_stdin();

    if(mult == 'y') {
        printf("\nEnter name for Player 2:\n>");
        fgets (player2, 20, stdin);
    } else {
        printf("\nThe CPU will be your opponent!\n");
        strcpy(player2, DEF);
    }

    printf("\n\nPlayer 1: %s\nPlayer 2: %s", player1, player2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `scanf` always null-terminates the strings it writes for `%s`, so the explicit `'\0'` assignments are pointless.  On the other hand, it reads as many characters as there are, so you might want to use `%20s` to prevent buffer overruns.

Comment: @Rizier123 It helps a lot! Though now it just skips the "Is there a player 2" part altogether. I input player 1, and the rest of the program runs

Comment: @Rizier123, It still skips through to the end. What do the new lines do?

Comment: @LeonardoOlvera are you sure? Test it again! Also the second question is a y/n!

Comment: @Rizier123, This version is much better! Thank you so much again!